# MS Word via the COM-object interface to add an image to the substrate / watermark

Tags: c#, powershell, ms-word, com

Sorry for the text – this is a translation …

How can I use the COM interface of the MS Word class to set the "Substrate/Background" "Confidential"?
[image]

In many forums, the examples use the example of adding to the header:

```
$doc = $word.Documents.Open("doc.docx")
$doc.Sections[1].Headers[1].Shapes.AddPicture("sec.png")
```

But I want to add the background to the body of the entire document. Similar to Excel, which has a function:

```
$worksheet.SetBackgroundPicture("sec.png")
```

It seems to me that in Word, the property is responsible for this _Document.Background (maybe I'm wrong https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/microsoft.office.interop.word._document.background) but I can't do how to replace the Shape object type …

Comment: Have a look [here](https://www.erickscottjohnson.com/blog--examples/how-to-watermark-word-documents-with-powershell)

Comment: And here the problem is that they change useful content. That is, an image is inserted Inside the page itself and formatted ... ($args[0].Shapes.AddShape(1,0, 0, 500, 125), where the argument is a $Word object.Documents.Open). Need watermark in the background! To avoid changing the content ...

Comment: You could capture the shape you've added in a variable and try `$shape.ZOrder(msoSendToBack)`. [msoZOrder enum](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/office.msozordercmd)

Comment: Theo, thank you for the idea! :) Now I know exactly what `_Document.Background` is not what I need! If I do `$doc.Background.Fill.UserPicture("sec.png")`. If I save the document, open it, and turn on the web view mode, then watermark will be displayed :). Almost what I need.

Comment: Yes, i've read somewhere that setting the `.Background` property oinly shows in webview mode. Hope the background shapes  gets you further!

Comment: I believe what you're describing is a "watermark": an image that's behind the text and "greyed" so that content above it is still clear? YES, this needs to be added to a Header (or a Footer) if it should appear on every page. So, with that information, what *exactly* is your problem? At what point are you stuck?

Comment: Да простят меня модераторы, но я не могу объяснить мысль переводя на английский язык ... Буду писать на двух языках.
Word документ это некоторая абстракция: 1. Колонтитул - хранит специальные служебные данные, метки, логотипы. 2. Тело документа - редактируемая область. 3. Подложка (фон) - некоторая загадочная область, которой можно присвоить фон через графический интерфейс (картинка в вопросе), но не понятно как сделать через COM.

Comment: Проблема: Тело - изменять нельзя! Имитировать водяной знак (добавлять изображение в фон) внутри тела нельзя! Колонтитул - хороший вариант, но не совсем то! Потому что, здесь могут быть полезные даные пользователя, можно случайно испортить! Нужно найти управление именно доступом к подложке (фоном) всего документа - который глобальный для всего документа, который появляется на всех страницах и предназначен только для того, чтобы хранить фон!

Comment: May the moderators forgive me, but I can't explain the idea by translating it into English ... I will write in two languages.
Word document is some abstraction: 1. Footer-stores special service data, tags, and logos. 2. The document body is the area to edit. 3. Background-some mysterious area that can be assigned a background via the graphical interface (the picture in question), but it is not clear how to do it via COM.

Comment: Problem: you can't change the Body! You can't imitate a watermark (add an image to the background) inside a body! The footer is a good option, but not quite that! Because, there may be useful user data, you can accidentally spoil it! You need to find the control of access to the background of the entire document-which is global for the entire document, which appears on all pages and is intended only to store the background!

Comment: Cindy Meister, When I make $worksheet.SetBackgroundPicture("sec.png") I see in the GUI that the global property of the background is set!

Comment: It seems impossible to do this ... https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/632e8f9a-7407-4d26-b9c5-740f62ac48e6/ms-word-via-the-comobject-interface-to-add-an-image-to-the-substrate-watermark